# Why doesn't git diff work on the command line for me?

Tags: git, diff

Every piece of documentation I've read on git (including the online book and the built-in help) says I can type "git diff" from command line, but whenever I do that I get:

`usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>`

Here's what I've tried so far (all are examples from the documentation):

```
$ git diff
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

$ git diff HEAD
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

$ git diff --
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

$ git diff -- .
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

$ git diff --stat
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>

$ git --version
git version 1.7.1
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Oops... stackoverflow removed everything between angle brackets and removed the linefeed after each line that ends in a "tag".  The "usage" text should be on the next line.
The actual error message with parenthesis instead of angle brackets:
"usage: git diff [--no-index] (path) (path)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you actually inside a directory with a Git repository when you're running these? (`git rev-parse --git-dir`) The command needs to be able to find the repository and determine what your working tree is in order to produce useful output. Otherwise (if a repository cannot be identified), it defaults to being a plain recursive-diff command, and needs two paths to operate.

Comment: Yeah that was it.  The documentation makes no mention of this "feature" of git diff.  How did you guys know about this mode of operation?

Comment: @Karl: From the [ *git diff* manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html): “If exactly two paths are given, and at least one is untracked, compare the two files / directories. This behavior can be forced by --no-index.”

Answer (score 1):

Are you working in a git repository? If you do a git status, do you get something close to the following?

```
> $ git status
> # On branch develop.new_feature
> # Changed but not updated:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
> #
> # modified:   feature
> # modified:   www/jkll.jsp
> #
> # Untracked files:
> #   (use "git add <file>..." to include            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `git diff --no-index`. The `[]` means the argument is optional.